# Exclude Interceptors added by component-scan

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am including a jar which has a class which has component scan enabled for couple of packages which have interceptors. I want to include this jar and use this class but i dont want the interceptor being scanned to be used and want to define my own interceptor which has to be used. How can I ensure that the interceptor which is part of component scan within a class in the jar is excluded?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the included source JAR, I would recommend to remove component scanning configuration from the JAR. Component scanning should be set at the top most level to avoid these kind of problems, that is in your "final" WAR or JAR.

That said, you still can :

1. Include all configuration from the JAR and use `exclude-filter` configuration to exclude all interceptors of a specific package for example
2. **OR** do not include configuration from the JAR and rewrite piece of configuration you need

It depends on how much (and what) Spring configuration is included in the JAR.

Comment: Thanks Gael. I don't  have access to the source. I did try exclude filter , but it does't seem to be excluding the component scans which are performed within the jar. It just excludes the unwanted classes from packages that I have included in my code. I was able to create a class on my own and not use the class within the jar (which I assume is the second option you are suggesting) , but wanted to see if I can avoid duplicating the code.

Comment: If you could provide a quick sample of the configurations, it might help but from what I understand there's no way to do what you are asking.